# Photos are grainy when imported in illustrator?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, print-design, pictures

So I got some raw pictures from a client for some business cards, they all look grainy when imported to illustrator

I tried to edit the pictures and export them to JPG, but they still look grainy in illustrator.

Here are the meta info [image]

Comment: Do you have the latest version of Adobe Raw installed?

Comment: Could it have something to do with the display quality setting and only be the way it is displayed? Just a thought.

Comment: Did you paste, "place as link," or "import" them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try resizing your image in Photoshop first to the actual dimensions you will be using in your Illustrator files and re-link your image. I suspect the large dimensions are what is causing the wonkiness.

Comment: I agree. The metafile shows an image suitable for printing at 15 x 10 inches @ 300dpi. The OP should at least pre-process it for postage stamp size using Photoshop before placing it. In addition, the "grainy" quality may be a low-res working preview. Perhaps a PDF at for-print quality may look different.

Answer (score 1):

Illustrator is a vector imaging program. I think that RAW is not included as a compatible raster format for Illustrator and so I am not sure it can handle RAW files properly. I have no idea why the jpg version don't work, but it should work just fine if you convert the images in PSD file format.

Comment: It was not raw, I edited the image in Adobe raw, the problem was the resolution of the image, changing it to 100dpi fixed my problem